# contactform 7 autoselect states when click on country

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using contactform 7, select dropdown for countries, states, is it possible to make display respective states and cities when we select the particular country in first select dropdown
[image]

Comment: It is possible by calling an ajax to populate state on change event of country dropdown. similary you can populate cities. Check [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for jQuery ajax.

Comment: What is your id/class for the country select box and state select box ?

Comment: The respective id's are "countries", "states"

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-this-is-how-to-showhide-fields-with-jquery?replies=8

Answer (score 0):

Add following line to your `footer.php` or elsewhere.Give **same class** name to all **STATE** select box.

```
var $sub = $('select.states');

$('#countries').first().change(function () {    
    $sub.hide();
    if (this.selectedIndex > 0)
        $sub.eq(this.selectedIndex - 1).show();
}).change();
```

You can do similar thing for city also.

**NOTE:**Assuming that State select box is having `states` class name.